# Interrupt in driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, driver

I got a fun USB hid device which is not supported on Linux, so I have been trying to port it and to create a proper driver.
I have managed to understand how data are exchanged by using the driver on a vm and usbmon.

I manage to control the device with libusb. (my program is fine)
Here are the two most important lines to send data to the USB device.

```
    libusb_control_transfer(dev_handle, 0x21, 0x39, 0x200, 0x00, data + i, 8, 0);

    libusb_interrupt_transfer(dev_handle, 0x81, vide, 8, &actual, 300);
```

After, I have tried to create a char driver.

```
    r = usb_control_msg(dev->udev,
            usb_sndctrlpipe(dev->udev, 0),
            CTRL_REQUEST,
            CTRL_REQUEST_TYPE,
            CTRL_VALUE,
            CTRL_INDEX,
            data_to_send + j,
            8,
            HZ * 2);

    r = usb_interrupt_msg(dev->udev,
            usb_sndintpipe(dev->udev, 129), // 129 = 0x81
            vide,
            8,
            &k,
            300);
```

There is a negative return value of usb_interrupt_msg.
My endpoint is good: bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN

With libusb, everything works as it should,
while with the driver, it seems the interruption is not sent.

Do I miss something with the function usb_interrupt_msg? 
I have been reading a lot of documentation (libusb, usb from kernel...) but I don't find the answer.

Comment: You might consider using [hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) instead of writing a driver.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thank you for your advice. I want to write the driver to learn more about it, it is a personal challenge.